# svn: reload an old revision

Tags: svn, reload, revision

I'd like to reload an old revision of my repository. My current revision ist 645 and I'd like to have 642 as my current version. The changes from 642 to 645 are changes in the files and additional files. I use the common method for that:

```
svn merge -r 645:642 .
```

This does not work either:

```
svn merge -r HEAD:642 .
```

Nothing happens. Still the old reversion. But when I do the following:

```
svn up -r 642
```

The local copy works just fine. But i would like to commit it as my current revision. But when I use

```
svn ci -m "Revert"
```

It does nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to merge with HEAD. See [this article](http://blog.mafr.de/2008/05/13/revert-a-commit-in-svn/).

Answer (score 1):

You are close. You did the merge but forgot to commit afterwards.

```
svn commit -m "Reverted for whatever reason"
```

Don't forget to have the revision you are reverting from in your local workspace before issuing the revert command.

Comment: Did you do a `svn up` beforehand to pull down your latest rev? What does 'svn merge --dry-run -r:645:642` show you? For grins and giggles, also do a `svn diff -r:645:642`.

Comment: `svn merge --dry-run -r 645:642 .` nothing. `svn diff -r 645:642 .` is giving me all me changes form 642 to 645.